# I Want to create a MySql database in a docker container and execute few DDL and DML Statements in it while the container is starting up

Tags: mysql, docker

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: docker-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=user_management
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

The default database is created **"user_management"** and now I have files with DDL and DML statements in it that I want to execute i.e. DDL statement (create a table) and DML statements (Insert few users by default). Not by entering the bash and manually executing the statements but any automated docker way of loading the files that contain DDL and DML statements and execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql dockerhub says, files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d will be executed in the startup of container to the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  docker-mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
     container_name: docker-mysql
     environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=user_management
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
     volumes:
       - /yourscript:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

so as above, you can mount volume and add your DDL and DML scripts in that location. Then mysql would execute them on startup. `/yourscript` is the location of your scripts

Comment: Thanks, @Dilan Tharaka.
 The concept of  "files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d will be executed in the startup of container" this was helpful.
But when I used it as mentioned above using the volumes I got the following error 
"ERROR: for docker-mysql  Cannot create container for service docker-mysql: b'open \\\\.\\pipe\\docker_d4w_systray: The system cannot find the file specified.'"

Comment: Hence I used the following approach to solve the problem :
I created a Dockerfile with following content where I copied the sql file during the time of mysql-docker-image creation :

`FROM mysql:5.7
COPY create_table.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ `

This worked fine and created the required tables.

Comment: Great !!! In my case I just used Docker. Therefore I did exactly the same that you did. But I gave you this solution since you were using docker compose. Anyway, glad that you solved your problem :)